# Flink Multiple Windows on same source

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My flink application does the following:

1. Read data in form of records from Kafka
2. 8 kinds of keyby combination and 60s tumbling time window
3. Sink:elasticsearch

The code like this:

```
   DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

    DataStream<Bean> input = stream.filter(...).flatMap(...)
    DataStream<Bean1> s1 = input.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...).keyBy(key1).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)).process()

    DataStream<Bean1> s2 = input.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...).keyBy(key2).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)).process()

    DataStream<Bean1> s3 = input.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...).keyBy(key3).window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)).process()

    Then add ElasticsearchSink of each stream
```

But it doesn't work well. Running for a while throws an exception

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

Kafka is work well, so what's the problem？

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the underlying cause? Could the job be running out of memory, or experiencing checkpoint timeouts, or other resource issues? Does the job recover and restart cleanly on its own?

Comment: There is way too little information to help you. Which versions are you using? Are you using exactly once? Does it work with one window? What is the full exception.